# I accidentally deleted my Macintosh drive and now I'm stuck in boot loop

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, recovery

I can't boot up my MacBook Air M1. When I check in Recovery Mode, it doesn't show any drive. When I hold <kbd>Option</kbd>, I don't see any volume in the Apple SSD.

In Disk Utility I can't erase it nor do anything else.  When I try installing macOS again it doesn't show any drive to install it to. When I use `diskutil list` command my whole SSD is shown as “free space” with no identification.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Not sure how you got here, but wiping the drive is necessary now.  [Here are some steps to try](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392157/119271)

Comment: Can I get terminal commands to do the same cuz disk utilities don't work for me at this point

Comment: By making a bootable macOS system to plug into your Mac, either on an external drive or even a USB thumb drive. Anil's answer (in Allan's post cited above) will guide you.

Comment: Use this command `diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk0 1 GPT APFS "Macintosh HD" R`. That should create a brand new APFS container on your boot disk assuming it's `/dev/disk0`. Make sure you get the correct identifier by using `diskutil list` and looking for your physical disk.

Comment: Apple silicon disks are more complex than Intel - the old link above may not help you. If steps in https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchl82829c17/mac don't work for you, you will need a second Mac for these steps https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/apple-configurator-mac/apdd5f3c75ad/mac

Comment: I tried using the terminal command,but it said that my disk could not be unmounted because it was in a process 0 (kernel) so it didn't help

Comment: Can u tell me how to create a bootable USB drive using a windows laptop? Cuz the customer care told me to try that and , I'd like to mention one more thing that when I open disk utilities and click on get info I see that every single byte of my ssd has been used and it says it's not bootable and not verified, that's why I don't even get to see it in start up disk section

Comment: Are you booting using Internet Recovery?  Please provide the output of `didkutil list`

Comment: It shows my physical drive with no volumes (disk0) and then Mac OS base system****(not os x volume) that's all

Comment: The simplest thing is to take it to an Apple Store if you haven't got a second Mac (or the skills) to follow steps in 2nd link I gave above.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica  From the question and the comments I suspect the Mac is not in a state to boot from an external drive.

Comment: @Gilby so what should I do now ,cuz the nearest store is like 60km and telling parents would cause trouble